# How to count words and their associated groups?

Tags: python, performance, loops, dictionary, counter

I would like to count the number of times a specific topic is brought up in a very long list of words. Currently, I have a dictionary of dictionaries where the outer keys are the topics and the inner keys are the keywords of that topic.

I am trying to efficiently count the keyword occurrences and maintain a cumulative sum of their corresponding topic occurrences.

Ultimately, I want to save the output for multiple texts. This is an example of what I currently have implemented. The issues I have with it are that it is extremely slow and that it does not store the keyword counts in the output DataFrame. Is there an alternative that resolves these issues?

```
import pandas as pd

topics = {
    "mathematics": {
        "analysis": 0,
        "algebra": 0,
        "logic": 0
    },
    "philosophy": {
        "ethics": 0,
        "metaphysics": 0,
        "epistemology": 0
    }
}

texts = {
    "text_a": [
        "the", "major", "areas", "of", "study", "in", "mathematics", "are",
        "analysis", "algebra", "and", "logic", "in", "philosophy", "they",
        "are", "ethics", "metaphysics", "and", "epistemology"
    ],
    "text_b": [
        "logic", "is", "studied", "both", "in", "mathematics", "and",
        "philosophy"
    ]
}

topics_by_text = pd.DataFrame()
for title, text in texts.items():
    topic_count = {}
    for topic, sub_dict in topics.items():
        curr_topic_counter = 0
        for keyword, count in sub_dict.items():
            keyword_occurrences = text.count(keyword)
            topics[topic][keyword] = keyword_occurrences
            curr_topic_counter += keyword_occurrences
        topic_count[topic] = curr_topic_counter
    topics_by_text[title] = pd.Series(topic_count)


print(topics_by_text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the speed, But the following code stores the keywords count in a neat MultiIndexed fashion.

```
# Returns a count dictionary 
def CountFrequency(my_list, keyword): 
    freq = {} 
    for item in my_list: 
      freq[item] = 0
      if (item in freq): 
          freq[item] += 1
      else: 
          freq[item] = 1

    dict_ = {}
    for your_key,value in keyword.items():
      try:
        dict_.update({your_key: freq[your_key]})
      except:
        dict_.update({your_key: 0})

    dict_['count'] = sum([value if (value != None) else 0 for value in dict_.values()])
    return dict_
```

```
# Calculates count
output = {}
for key, value in texts.items():
  for topic, keywords in topics.items():
    try:
      output[topic][key] = CountFrequency(value,keywords)
    except KeyError:
      output[topic] = {}
      output[topic][key] = CountFrequency(value,keywords)
```

```
# To DataFrame
dict_of_df = {k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k,v in output.items()}
df = pd.concat(dict_of_df, axis=0)
df.T
```